# how to keep a private and public branch in sync

Tags: git, version-control, github, branching-and-merging

Lets say I have a local repo with two branches. A private branch with a bunch of private info that I push to a deployment server and a public branch with all of that private security info removed which I push to a public repo like github. What's the best way to keep these branches in sync? Basically I want one branch to selectively "pull" from the other branch without touching those sensitive configuration files, but I still want those sensitive configuration files with security info tracked in the private branch. Would this even be the right work flow?

Comment: Do all the work on the public branch and only pull it into the private branch when you're ready to deploy.  As long as the "sensitive" files don't exist in the public branch you're all set.

Answer (score 1):

One idea is tracking your local branch and rebasing the secret commit on the tip of your branch:

```
git checkout -b private --track public
git add secret_file
git commit
#update public
git pull --rebase
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered having separate repositories?  All it takes is one unnoticed goof, and you've accidentally pushed sensitive files to a public place.  I think I'd prefer separate repositories to mitigate any risk, and then use shell or build scripts to place the sensitive artifacts in the right directory.